# Duplicate the Row's Expect the Index Column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to Duplicate the row's based on the another column values but expect the Index not be duplicate.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': [0, 1, 2], 'Name': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'val': [3, 1, 2]}, index=['DC', 'BB', 'BS']); df

df.reset_index(level=0,inplace = True)

pd.DataFrame(df.values.repeat(df.val, axis=0), columns=df.columns)


Input:

  index Date Name val
0    DC    0    A   3
1    DC    0    A   3
2    DC    0    A   3
3    BB    1    B   1
4    BS    2    C   2
5    BS    2    C   2
```

***Expected Output Format:***

```
  index Date Name val
0    DC    0    A   3
1          0    A   3
2          0    A   3
3    BB    1    B   1
4    BS    2    C   2
5          2    C   2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test duplicates by some column, e.g. by `df1['index']` and set empty strings by [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) and `loc`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.values.repeat(df.val, axis=0), columns=df.columns)
df1.loc[df1['index'].duplicated(), 'index'] = ''
print (df1)
  index Date Name val
0    DC    0    A   3
1          0    A   3
2          0    A   3
3    BB    1    B   1
4    BS    2    C   2
5          2    C   2

print (df1.dtypes)
index    object
Date     object
Name     object
val      object
dtype: object
```

But if want avoid convert all values to `object`s use [`Index.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.duplicated.html) with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and for test 
[`Index.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.duplicated.html):

```
df1 = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df.val)]
df1.loc[df1.index.duplicated(), 'index'] = ''
df1 = df1.reset_index(drop=True)
print (df1)
  index  Date Name  val
0    DC     0    A    3
1           0    A    3
2           0    A    3
3    BB     1    B    1
4    BS     2    C    2
5           2    C    2

print (df1.dtypes)
index    object
Date      int64
Name     object
val       int64
dtype: object
```